# Like the period in "Mr." is there a German word that has a period in it?

Tags: abbreviation

Like we say in English "Mr. Brown" and the period is connected to "Mr", is there such a thing in German language?

Comment: The German attribute equvalent _Herr_ is usually written out for all what I know. The only one that comes to my mind is _Frl._ for _Fräulein_, but that's no more used nowadays.

Comment: *Mr.* is an abbreviation no longer identified as such. IIRC, it's an error to write *Mister Brown*. This isn't the case for German *Hr.* and *Herr*, they are both ok.

Comment: Ja, auch im Deutschen gibt es Abkürzungen, oder was ist die Frage?

Comment: I would a Hr. (Fr.) Braun understand, but checking the comments here, it is likely not correct. I am not a native speaker.

Comment: But there is no full stop after the r in Mr Smith! ;)

Answer (score 8):

If you are looking for words in general that are commonly abbreviated, there is lots of them:

- usw. - und so weiter (and so forth)
- Dr. - Doktor (person with a PhD)
- u. a. - unter anderem (among others)
- o. Ä. - oder Ähnliche(s) (or similar)
- Str. - Straße (in a street name)

If you *really* need to abbreviate *Herr* or *Frau*, you can use Hr. and Fr., but you should not use it in a formal context or a salutation, as it might be considered disrespectful.

Comment: "u. a." and "o. Ä." need to be separated by space.

Comment: `z.B.` for `zum Beispiel` ("for instance")

Comment: Inwiefern soll Hr. Beispielgeber in einem formalen Kontext respektlos sein?

Comment: Wenn es um eine Respektperson geht, kann die Abkürzung nicht immer angebracht sein.

Comment: @userunknown: Nicht die Anrede selbst ist respektlos, aber es kann respektlos wirken, wenn man sich nicht einmal bei kurzen Wörtern die Zeit nimmt, diese auszuschreiben, statt sie abzukürzen. Bei "Hr." spart man im Vergleich zu "Herr" genau einen Tastenanschlag.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Wer solche Lappalien gegen sich auslegt, der legt es drauf an und findet sicher sonst was; das ist ja schon paranoide Textinterpretation. Kein normaler Mensch würde über ein Hr. auch nur stolpern. Wahrscheinlich ist es der Schreiber einfach gewohnt Herr mit Hr. abzukürzen. Von Anrede war i.d. Frage übrigens nicht die Rede; nur in der Antwort OElrims, und da alternativ zu "formalem Kontext" und nach letzterem hatte ich ausdrücklich gefragt. Wer pedantisch zu werden vorhat sollte zumindest genau lesen. Dann widerlegst Du noch Dein Argument, dass man gar nicht nennenswert Zeit spart.

Comment: @userunknown: Wer irgendetwas wie für oder gegen sich auslegt, ist irrelevant. Einen Text um jeden Preis abzukürzen, wenn keine räumliche Beschränkung vorliegt, zeugt nun mal unweigerlich davon, dass man das Schreiben so schnell wie möglich hinter sich bringen wollte. Es mag manchmal angemessen sein, das offen zu zeigen, respektvoll ist es aber sicherlich nicht. "Kein normaler Mensch würde über ein Hr. auch nur stolpern." - hast du einen Beleg für diese Behauptung? Meiner eigenen Beobachtung nach stolpere zumindest ich über jede Abkürzung an sich kurzer Wörter wie "u." und "Hr.", weil ich ...

Comment: ... dann jedes Mal einen Moment lang darüber nachdenke, wieso der Schreiber das Wort nicht einfach ausgeschrieben hat. In der Tat gelten meine Anmerkungen genauso für andere Vorkommen von "Hr." als in Anreden, da hast du Recht. Dass man nennenswert Zeit spart, habe ich nicht behauptet; nur, dass offenbar der dringende Wunsch da war, um jeden Preis Zeit zu sparen - so stark, dass man gar nicht mehr darüber nachdenkt, ob tatsächlich nennenswert Zeit gespart wird, sondern viele Wörter reflexartig abkürzt.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Wer sagt Dir, dass jmd. den Text um jeden Preis abkürzen wollte? Wer sagt Dir, dass keine räumliche Beschränkung vorliegt? Das sind doch rein spekulative Annahmen. Erst vermutest Du, es zeuge unweigerlich davon, dass der Schreiber das Schreiben hinter sich bringen wolle. Um diese abenteuerliche Annahme zu stützen bist Du dann bereit dem Schreiber auch noch Idiotie zu unterstellen; dass er nicht merkt, dass die Ersparnis marginal ist, obwohl er das so oft tut, dass es schon reflexartig ist. Wie kann man wissen, dass es reflexartig war? Ebensogut könnte man phantasieren, …

Comment: ... der Schreiber wolle vom allgemeinen, unspezifischen "Herr" rasch zum persönlichen "Brown" kommen. Oder der Schreiber hat Angst, die Tinte könnte gleich ausgehen. Auch weißt Du nicht, ob der Schreiber nicht eine halbe Stunde über die Abkürzung gebrütet hat und zu ganz anderen Spekulationen gelangt ist, die der Leser anstellen könnte. Er könnte auch denken, dass eine Abkürzung zu verwenden den Angesprochenen nicht dem Verdacht aussetzt, ein pedantischer, paranoider und eitler Fatzke zu sein, der mit derlei Überlegungen seine Zeit verplempert, Oswald Rainhold Mapper.

Comment: @userunknown: "Wer sagt Dir, dass jmd. den Text um jeden Preis abkürzen wollte?" - die Tatsache, dass auch dort abgekürzt wurde, wo dies kaum eine Verringerung der Textlänge erbrachte. "Wer sagt Dir, dass keine räumliche Beschränkung vorliegt?" - das lässt sich aus dem Kontext erschließen. "Das sind doch rein spekulative Annahmen." - nur, wenn man sich nicht über den eben erwähnten Kontext informiert. "dass er nicht merkt, dass die Ersparnis marginal ist" - wenn er's merkt, warum kürzt er dann ab? Der humoristische zweite Teil deines Kommentars war sehr amüsant.

Answer (score 7):

If you write *Hr.* instead of *Herr* or *Fr.* instead of *Frau* you save only one character - but render the text more difficult to read. These abbreviations are not uncommon, but usually the words are spelt out.

The situation may be different, in situations like the following:

> Sehr geehrter Hr. Prof. Dr. med. Dr. h.c. Mayer, [..]

**Edit:**

- Please see [Abkür­zungen](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/abkuerzungen) for information about German abbreviations (in German) and many examples (not all of them ending with a period).
- If you want to present *Doctor honoris causa* and many other abbreviations typographically correct, you need a narrow no-break space (NNBSP; unicode U+202F). If the choice is between no space or a normal, full space, I consider the omission of the space as the lesser evil, notwithstanding DIN 5008. Usage is divided.

  > In Abkürzungen: „z. B.“ – z. B. Hier sollte eigentlich besser ein schmales geschütztes Leerzeichen („z. B.“ – z. B.) stehen. Aus Kompatibilitätsgründen wird jedoch in der Regel darauf verzichtet, da dieses Zeichen nicht von allen Webbrowsern und Schriftarten unterstützt wird. Häufig wird der Zwischenraum stattdessen auch ganz weggelassen, was jedoch gemäß DIN 5008 nicht korrekt ist.
  > [Wikipedia "Geschütztes Leerzeichen"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gesch%C3%BCtztes_Leerzeichen)

Comment: Off topic: Abbreviations, which consist of several words are typeset with a small space in between. So, write o. ä. or z. B.

Comment: Den Zwischenraum wegzulassen ist zwar nicht korrekt, aber wenn man keinen Einfluss darauf hat, wie der Text im Ausgabegerät umgebrochen wird, verhindert man so einen ungewollten Umbruch dazwischen. Für mich ein Gund mich oft über diese Regel hinwezusetzen (auch bei 14 km/14km etc.).

Answer (score 3):

It is not only certain words that have a dot in German writing. It is literally every word that is abbreviated. You can do this with every word, at least in principle. Of course, writing sentences like

> H. Mayer hat gestern im städt. Freib. Schwimmunt. gegeben.

is not very common. You need a good reason and the right environment for using abbreviations on words that are not usually abbreviated (as usw., etc., u.a., z.B. and the others that have been mentioned by other contributors).

However, in dictionaries and encylopediae you will find the lemmata (topical words of an article) quite regularly abbreviated in order to save space. E.g. you may find something like.

> Regensburg. Stadt in Bayern, an der Donau. R. geht auf die römische Siedlung Castra Regina aus dem 2. Jhd. zurück. Erste Besiedlung R.s ist nachgewiesen für das 3. Jtsd. v. Chr. Heute ist R. ein Mittelzentrum mit Universität, Behörden, Leichtindustrie und Tourismus.

(Don't take the information too literally, I made it up, more or less just to give an example.)

Comment: "every word that is abbreviated" - this is very important remark to be made here. Unlike English, German does not have a (more or less compulsory) rule or preference to put a period only after abbreviations that end on a different letter than the full word.

Answer (score 2):

In Germany we have a long list of abbreviations for written German, e.g. for official letters.

Here is a list of the [most common abbreviations](https://www.bundesanzeiger-verlag.de/fileadmin/Fachverlag/Autorenservice/Handout_Abkuerzungen_Z-I_9.9.15.pdf) in PDF format.

A academic degrees is part of the name in Germany. Spelling of professor, doctor and graduate engineer as well as professional titles:

> Prof. Dr. Hans Mustermann
>
> Dr. Claudia Mustermann
>
> Dipl.-Ing. Marcus Mustermann

Bachelor and Master degrees (such as B. A., B. SC., M. A., M. Sc.) are behind the name:

> Sebastian Schmidt B. A.